# Can't access some Apple services on my home Wi-Fi

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, wifi, system-settings, internet

I have a 2019 MacBook Pro, which I use mostly at school, but when I use it at home I can't use Safari, Apple Music, App Store, access iCloud settings, or even install updates from the System Preferences.

I initially thought there might have been a problem with the internet service provider itself, but I can access these services from my phone. I then checked if maybe there was a problem with the connection on my laptop, but other browsers seem to work fine. And what's even more strange is that in school I can use all those features just fine, but once I get home and connect to my home router, they just stop working. It's as though only the apple applications that require an internet connection don't work.

One thing that does happen though is in Safari when I Google search from the address bar, it doesn't load instantly, but after a long while when I chance upon Safari again, the webpage has partially loaded. This only happens with Safari. The other apps don't work at all. App Store, Apple Music, updates, doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem that you have, is your IP address is setup on manual for your home Wifi or something like that ?

Because for me the solution was that the IP address of my home Wifi were configured on manual on the network settings of the Mac (something that I did for some reasons) and once I switched to DHCP, everything worked fine again.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know too much about IP addresses and stuff like that, so if you could walk me through how to get that configured or at least checked.